# Non-Trivial Matrix Puzzles

Tags: progressive-matrix

Someone said in a random WA group that these are from one of the free online Mensa tests. Exact source unknown. Nobody seem to be able to figure out solid rules, so I thought "Hey, maybe Puzzling is the place. Seen a lot of brainpower here." Any takers?

The images are copyrighted and can not be displayed without permission.

Comment: Closing as "requires attribution", though really the problem is more exactly "requires images, which are no longer here and can't be reproduced here for copyright reasons".

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> For the second problem, the answer could be: 
>  [image] 
>  In each row the figure seems to rotate $90^\circ$ clockwise from each column to the next. If the figure doesn't have a central dot, a dot and a black semicircle are added. If it has a central dot, the dot and a white semicircle are removed. If we apply this to the bottom row, the last figure in that row becomes the one above.

Comment: I think you might be on to something. Think it fits logically actually. We need your brain also on the first matrix and/or here <https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91452/visual-sequential-logic-iq-task> Also sequential.